# How do I get merchant chest without moving through walls?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It is really hard to find gold and merchant chest are my best bet and I want to buy a home.  I have tried moving through walls and it corrupted my Xbox 360

Answer (score 1):

There is only one merchant chest you can enter without glitching through walls. The merchant is the khajiit caravan at Dawnstar. Go to the mine near the longhouse an go the area on the left where there's a stone. It should say when looking at the ground *open chest*. Another one is at Solitude khajiit caravan. Try searching the ground for it. it's very hard. Those are the only chests unfortunately. There are other ways of making money in Skyrim too, such as:

1. Smithing, improving, and enchanting armor and weapons.
2. Making valuable potions with rare ingredients.
3. As Matthew said, do the Thieves' Guild radiant quests so you can earn a few hundred gold each job. In addition, do the bedlam jobs to earn a few hundred gold, and earn more by selling the stolen items to Tonilla.